# Error while creating an application for Blockchain

Tags: python, django, blockchain

I've installed `Python 3.6` and `Django 2.2.`6 used the following code to install virtual environment.

```
pip install virtualenv

virtualenv venv

venv\Scripts\activate
```

After that,
I've installed `Django 2.2.6` and trying create a project and application for blockchain

```
pip install django==2.2.6

django-admin startproject PyChain

cd PyChain

python manage.py createapp blockchain
```

I'm getting the error `"No module name : django"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of - `python manage.py createapp blockchain` 
Use -    `python manage.py startapp blockchain`   
OR - `django-admin startapp blockchain`